# d3.js title above responsive chart with fixed aspect ratio

Tags: d3.js, donut-chart

I am very new to programming in d3.js, and I was wondering if someone could help me out with the following:

I have modified a donut chart that I found on the web. I modified it to become **responsive** while still maintaining an **aspect ratio of 1** for the circular donut chart. I was wondering what the best way would be **to place a title above or below it**. I have tried various approaches but I am unable to create one that works consistently.

Simplified JSFiddle here:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/flo12392/ve9884su/)

code also attached here:

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var x = {
  value: 80.43,
  color1: "#007EA7",
  color2: "#d9d9d9"
};

var margin = {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 10
};

width = Math.min(width - margin.left - margin.right,
  height - margin.top - margin.bottom);
height = width * 1; // Should be a perfect circle.

svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .classed("svg-container", true)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width) + " " + (height))
  .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);


// Below is code to create the actual donut chart. It used the width and height attributes calculated above. 

var outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  innerRadius = (outerRadius / 5) * 4;

τ = 2 * Math.PI;
fontSize = (Math.min(width, height) / 5);

arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
  .startAngle(0);

var background = svg.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: τ
  })
  .style("fill", x.color2)
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var text = svg.append("text")
  .text(Math.round(x.value * 10) / 10 + '%')
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", fontSize + 'px')
  .attr("dy", height / 2 + fontSize / 2.5)
  .attr("dx", width / 2);

foreground = svg.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: x.value / 100 * τ
  })
  .style("fill", x.color1)
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

```css
.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.svg-content-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Any comments, advise, references or code snippets that might help me are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on this question in the future: I decided to place my title below the chart and managed to solve it by slightly cheating.

I used the following CSS:

```css
.svg-container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.svg-content-responsive {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.svg-gauge-title-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-50px;

}

.svg-gauge-title {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

i.e. I added 50px of padding-bottom to the chart, and also added a title container with 50px of margin above. Might not be the cleanest way, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong with adding something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ve9884su/1/):

```
var title = svg.append("text") 
    .text('This is the title') 
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle") 
    .style("font-size", '12px') 
    .attr("dy", 10)
    .attr("dx", width / 2);
```

exactly like the `text`?

<sub>PS: adding your approaches that failed would help people answer the question</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is indeed one of the approaches that I tried, but the issue is that the title will disappear from the div, like so:

http://oi68.tinypic.com/2v9yyqg.jpg

I am hestitant to list my attempts at solving this here, as I might very well have executed the attempts poorly. So the solution itself might be valid but my execution of it could have been the problem..